# Solve the differential equation $y=2\sqrt{x}y^2y'+4xy'$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the following differential equation:
>   $$
> y=2\sqrt{x}y^2y'+4xy'
> $$

The main problem for me is to understand what type of DE it is, since it is neither of these:

- Separable
- Homogeneous
- Linear
- Exact
- Bernoulli
- Riccati
- Implicit
- Lagrange

Perhaps I am missing something. But how should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$y=2\sqrt{x}y^2y'+4xy'$$
It's Bernoulli's differential equation if you consider $x'$ instead of $y'$
$$yx'-4x=2\sqrt{x}y^2$$